# Evaluating $\int\sqrt{1 + \frac1{x^2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

How do I solve this integral?
$$\int \sqrt{1 + \frac1{x^2}}\mathrm dx$$

I tried substituting $x=\cot t$ but ended up getting another tricky integral, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a [solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8tft5rdo5xiejbd/Integral%20Answer.pdf?dl=0) via Wolfram|Alpha with all steps explained--but perhaps an answer by a user here will be more informative. It doesn't look very pretty, regardless.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $\dfrac1x=\sinh t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use $x = \tan \theta $. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :$$I=\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx+\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx,\\
\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=-\int\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$